# Cannot set Text on button

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to set Text on button.
Here is my code:

```
btn = new Button();
btn.Content = "A";


btn.Height = '*';
btn.Width = 200;
btn.Margin = new Thickness(10);
btn.Padding = new Thickness(100);
btn.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
btn.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, column);
btn.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);
```

[image]

Everything is working fine except I can't display text on button. 
Please guide me in the right direction!

Comment: can you show us your xaml code?

Comment: I'm guessing the height ins invalid . try just for a test  to set height to 40

Comment: @eranotzap still not working!

Comment: @Domysee There's nothing in the xaml except the Grid defntion.

Comment: … did you add the button to the grid?

Comment: where does the `btn` variable come from?

Comment: This is the output I am getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your width is 200 and your padding (which shrinks the content's space from all directions) is 100, there is no more space for your content. Try using a smaller (or no) padding.